# CSS slider — как сделать кликабельными все ссылки?

Tags: css3

Непонятная проблема с CSS слайдером. В каждом слайде свой внутренний блок со своей ссылкой Подробнее. Внешне все показывается как надо, но при клике на ссылку Подробнее с любого слайда всегда кликается ссылка с последнего слайда.

Рабочий пример: https://codepen.io/Kripto77/pen/NvbQbM

Танцы с display:none и z-index не помогли.

Пожалуйста помогите решить проблему

```css
.slides {
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.slides ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
 margin:0
}
.slides ul li {
    top:0;
 width:100%; 
    height:400px;
 background-size:cover;
 opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:flex-end;
 align-items:center;

    /* css3 animation */
    animation-name: anim_slides;
    animation-duration: 24.0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
/* keyframes #anim_slides */
@keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
    }
}

/* css3 delays */
.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
    animation-delay: 12.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
    animation-delay: 18.0s;
}
.sinner { right:10%; margin-left:50px;  padding:20px 20px 50px; width:100%; max-width:400px; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; background:rgba(255,255,255,.7); position:relative; overflow:hidden; 
    animation-name: anim_titles;
    animation-duration: 24.0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
.sinner a { right:10px; bottom:10px; padding:10px; color:#fff !important; background: rgba(90,206,231,.7); display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; position:absolute}
.stext { margin:1% 0}
.stitle { font-size:150%}

.s1 { background:grey}
.s2 { background:green}
.s3 { background:blue}
.s4 { background:silver}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
 <ul>
   <li class="s1">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 1</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 1</div>
    <a href="/link1">Подробнее 1 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

   <li class="s2">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 2</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 2</div>
    <a href="/link2">Подробнее 2 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="s1">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 3</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 3</div>
    <a href="/link3">Подробнее 3 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

   <li class="s4">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 4</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 4</div>
    <a href="/link4">Подробнее 4 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена - надо скрывать неиспользуемые слайды через visibility: hidden

```css
.slides {
    height:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}
.slides ul {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
 margin:0
}
.slides ul li {
    top:0;
 width:100%; 
    height:400px;
 background-size:cover;
 opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:flex-end;
 align-items:center;

    /* css3 animation */
    animation-name: anim_slides;
    animation-duration: 24.0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/* keyframes #anim_slides */
@keyframes anim_slides {
    0% {
        opacity:0;
        visibility: visible;
    }
    6% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    24% {
        opacity:1;
    }
    30% {
        opacity:0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

/* css3 delays */
.slides ul  li:nth-child(2), .slides ul  li:nth-child(2) div {
    animation-delay: 6.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(3), .slides ul  li:nth-child(3) div {
    animation-delay: 12.0s;
}
.slides ul  li:nth-child(4), .slides ul  li:nth-child(4) div {
    animation-delay: 18.0s;
}
.sinner { right:10%; margin-left:50px;  padding:20px 20px 50px; width:100%; max-width:400px; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; background:rgba(255,255,255,.7); position:relative; overflow:hidden; 
    animation-name: anim_titles;
    animation-duration: 24.0s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-direction: normal;
    animation-delay: 0;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}
.sinner a { right:10px; bottom:10px; padding:10px; color:#fff !important; background: rgba(90,206,231,.7); display:inline-block; text-decoration:none; position:absolute}
.stext { margin:1% 0}
.stitle { font-size:150%}

.s1 { background:grey}
.s2 { background:green}
.s3 { background:blue}
.s4 { background:silver}
```

```html
<div class="slides">
 <ul>
   <li class="s1">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 1</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 1</div>
    <a href="/link1">Подробнее 1 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

   <li class="s2">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 2</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 2</div>
    <a href="/link2">Подробнее 2 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="s1">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 3</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 3</div>
    <a href="/link3">Подробнее 3 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

   <li class="s4">
   <div class="sinner">
    <div class="stitle">Слайд 4</div>
    <div class="stext">Описание слайда 4</div>
    <a href="/link4">Подробнее 4 >></a>
   </div>
  </li>

 </ul>
</div>
```